# Learning a little about using interface variable

Tags: java, interface

I recently saw implementing where a interface is implemented in a class and in another class we have a static final variable of the interface type and it somehow was able to complete computation from the class that had implemented the interface .

My question is how will the interface variable handle this if more than one class has a implementation of the interface. Am I missing something or it is just guessing where the implementation of interface is .

This is for java language

```
public interface DemoMe{
  public void doSomething();
}

public class MainClass implements demoMe {
   public void doSomething(){
     System.out.println("Something was done ");
   }
}

public class AnotherClass { 
  private final DemoMe demoVariable;

  public void useMe(){
    demoVariable.doSomething();
   }
}
```

here the  AnotherClass somehow knows how to look for implementation of doSomething. can someone point me towards how this exactly works.

Comment: Please add tag for language you are asking question about. Based on "final" it is probably Java, but hard to tell. Generally questions without language tags stay unanswered...

Comment: thanks for that updated the comment

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please provide code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are interface variables static and final by default?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430756/why-are-interface-variables-static-and-final-by-default)

Comment: I dont think it is what I am exactly looking for

Comment: if you call `useMe` method on your another class, it will use implementation which you provide, doesnt matter is ist only one or do you have hundred.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an interface in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321122/what-is-an-interface-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

The variables in java `interface` are `public` `static` and `final` type. You whenever a class implements an `interface`. The `interface variable` become part of the class. Now these variable can be accessed using `class reference` or `object reference`. These variable are `final` so **cannot be updated** and `static` so always belong to the class. The `interface` itself need not to manage anything. The implementing class will take care of it.

Here we have defined an interface `DemoMe` with one method and one variable. Now `DemoMeOne` class implements the interface. The need to provide the definition for methods coming from interface. The `doSomething()` method simply prints a statement an access the variable from interface. Now we define an other class which instantiate the `DemoMeOne` class and access the interface method and variable.

```
interface DemoMe{
  public void doSomething();
  public int variable = 100;
}

class DemoMeOne implements DemoMe {
  public void doSomething(){
    System.out.println("Something was done.");
    System.out.println("Access interface variable: " + variable);
  }
}

class MainClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DemoMeOne demoMeOne = new DemoMeOne();
    System.out.println("Variable from interface using DemoMeOnce class: " + DemoMeOne.variable);
    System.out.println("Variable from interface using DemoMeOnce object reference: " + demoMeOne.variable);
    System.out.println("Variable from interface using interface itself: " + DemoMe.variable);
    demoMeOne.doSomething();
  }
}
```

---

**output:**
Variable from interface using DemoMeOnce class: 100
Variable from interface using DemoMeOnce object reference: 100
Variable from interface using interface itself: 100
Something was done.
Access interface variable: 100