# RestAssured - ResponseBody print() method mysterious

Tags: java, rest-assured

Where is this print() method defined? I can't seem to figure out where the actual method is? It just seems to work like magic. I know what an interface is. I'm asking explicitly, if I run er.response().getBody().print(); then where is the print method defined for RestAssured? I haven't overridden it.

```
public interface ResponseBody<T extends ResponseBody<T>> extends ResponseBodyExtractionOptions {
    String print();
...
...
}
```

For example, I'm running:

```
er.response().getBody().print();
```

Yet none of the classes below print seem to have print defined.

Comment: Are you looking for the implementation? I don't understand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an interface in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321122/what-is-an-interface-in-java)

Comment: No, I know what an interface is. I'm asking explicitly, if I run er.response().getBody().print(); then where is the print method defined for RestAssured? I haven't overridden it.

Comment: Well, someone has. Call `getClass()` on the value returned by `getBody` to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the stupid downvotes. In fact, you were wrong, this wasn't an interface question.

I appreciate Sotirios Delimanolis' comment, I did not know about the getClass() method.

Running this method revealed print() is defined in the String class.