# java.lang.ClassCastException Converting object of class com.package1.Class1 to object of com.package2.Class2

Tags: java

Recently in my project I have encountered one issue I am casting an object of `com.package1.class1` to `com.package2.Class1` but its getting failed and giving me below error:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.package1.Class1 cannot be
>   cast to com.package2.Class1

and code snapshot is as below:

```java
if (savedState.containsKey(KEY_SCOREDNETWORKCACHE)) {
    ArrayList<TimestampedScoredNetwork> scoredNetworkArrayList =
            savedState.getParcelableArrayList(KEY_SCOREDNETWORKCACHE);
    for (TimestampedScoredNetwork timedScore : scoredNetworkArrayList) { //Exception received for this line

    }
}
```

Can anyone help how I can resolve this.

Comment: Casting is not converting.

Comment: You cannot cast one class to another just because they have the same `simpleName`. It does not have sense. They should have the same `fully queslified name` or be connected by `subtyping` of some sort.

Comment: it's impossible. They are not identical, even if they happen to share the same attributes and methods.

Comment: Can it be done by using Reflection ?

Comment: @BadmashCoder Maybe, but a rule of thumb is: use Reflection wisely, and use it only as last resort.

Comment: @BadmashCoder If your two eponymous classes are somehow related, your code should reflect that. See also [What is an interface in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321122/what-is-an-interface-in-java)