# What's the difference between these two java variable declarations?

Tags: java, variables, set, declaration, hashset

```
public class SomeClass {
    private HashSet<SomeObject> contents = new HashSet<SomeObject>();
    private Set<SomeObject> contents2 = new HashSet<SomeObject>();
}
```

What's the difference? In the end they are both a `HashSet` isn't it? The second one looks just wrong to me, but I have seen it frequently used, accepted and working.

Comment: I suggest brushing up on general object oriented programming concepts.

Comment: To expand on what others have said, the second is programming to an interface, the first is using a specific implementation.

Comment: http://pragmaticjava.blogspot.com/2008/08/program-to-interface-not-implementation.html

Comment: @colithium - I think that's exactly what the OP is doing...

Comment: okay thanks guys i got it :) altough i find it a bit contradicting that the majority supports a not so strict declaration. doesn't this somehow undermine the concept? please bear with me i come from the world of php where you can multiply strings ...

Comment: @Joe, for private variables only visible inside of classes, it honestly doesn't matter.  But for public facing properties, it gives you some leeway in that you can completely switch out how it's implemented without affecting the code that is using your class.  Also, when accepting parameters, callers like it when you accept the most general thing possible so they don't have to fanangle their data structure to match yours exactly

Comment: @Tony To be on topic, answers to this question can't go into depth about the relevant OO concepts.  A general primer would be helpful in my opinion.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`Set` is an interface, and `HashSet` is a class that implements the `Set` interface.

Declaring the variable as type `HashSet` means that no other implementation of `Set` may be used.  You may want this if you need specific functionality of `HashSet`.

If you do not need any specific functionality from `HashSet`, it is better to declare the variable as type `Set`.  This leaves the exact implementation open to change later.  You may find that for the data you are using, a different implementation works better.  By using the interface, you can make this change later if needed.

You can see more details here: [When should I use an interface in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586389/when-best-to-use-an-interface-in-java)

Comment: I would just add a link to this question : When best to use un interface in java, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586389/when-best-to-use-an-interface-in-java

Comment: Thanks, I added the link since it seems to have additional details that I did not include about when to use each.

Comment: @Tony Ennis - Thanks! This is by far the most votes I have had on an answer so far.

Answer (score 3):

Set is a collection interface that HashSet implements.

The second option is usually the ideal choice as it's more generic.

Answer (score 3):

Since the HashSet class implements the Set interface, its legal to assign a HashSet to a Set variable.  You could not go the other way however (assign a Set to a more specific HashSet variable).

Answer (score 3):

`Set` is an interface that `HashSet` implements, so if you do this:

`Set<E> mySet = new HashSet<E>();`

You will still have access to the functionality of `HashSet`, but you also have the flexibility to replace the concrete instance with an instance of another `Set` class in the future, such as `LinkedHashSet` or `TreeSet`, or another implementation.

The first method uses a concrete class, allowing you to replace the class with an instance of itself or a subclass, but with less flexibility. For example, `TreeSet` could not be used if your variable type was `HashSet`.

This is Item 52 from Joshua Bloch's [*Effective Java, 2nd Edition*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201310058).

> **Refer to Objects by their interfaces**
>
> ... You should favor the use of interfaces rather than classes to refer to objects. **If appropriate interface types exist, then parameters, return values, variables, and fields should all be declared using interface types.** The only time you really need to refer to an object's class is when you're creating it with a constructor...
>
> // **Usually Good - uses interface as type**
>
> `List<T> tlist = new Vector<T>();`
>
> // **Typically Bad - uses concrete class as type!**
>
> `Vector<T> vec = new Vector<T>();`

This practice does carry some caveats - if the implementation you want has special behavior not guaranteed by the generic interface, then you have to document your requirements accordingly.

For example, `Vector<T>` is `synchronized`, whereas `ArrayList<T>` (also an implementer of `List<T>`) does not, so if you required synchronized containers in your design (or not), you would need to document that.

Answer (score 2):

One thing worth to mention, is that interface vs. concrete class rule is most important for types exposed in API, eg. method parameter or return type. For private fields and variables it only ensures you aren't using any methods from concrete implementation (i.e. HashSet), but then it's private, so doesn't really matter.

Another thing is that adding another type reference will slightly increase size of your compiled class. Most people won't care, but these things adds up.