# When/why to use/define an interface

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When best to use an interface in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586389/when-best-to-use-an-interface-in-java)

Hi,

When defining a class should I always define a corresponding interface ?

What is the advantage of

```
List list = new ArrayList();
```

Why not just -

```
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
```

Thanks

Comment: @Mark: he's not asking when to use an interface, he's asking when/why he should define a variable with the interface type or the concrete class type.

Comment: @Jonah, in that case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147468/why-should-the-interface-for-a-java-class-be-prefered

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The advantage of doing the former allows you to switch out your implementation without having to re-declare your variable.

This way you can use ArrayList, LinkedList(anything that implements List) etc.

Answer (score 2):

The advantage is that you can change the implementation for another without having to change the rest of the code. For instance, you could use a LinkedList instead.

This improves maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of first way is it's shorter to type.

Comment: I seriously hope that's not the only advantage you see.

Comment: @delnan - I don't think mdma was serious at all. :)

Answer (score 0):

An `interface` is a contractual standard upon which other classes can be based. I like to think of it in the context of an API, or Application Programming Interface, which allows other developers to program against a standard set of methods. A class is obligated to implement the methods that the `interface` defines, but can also implement other private methods that may be undocumented (for example, utility methods used by the prescribed methods of the interface).