# How can I implement this class in Polymorphism c++?

Tags: c++, class, oop, polymorphism

I'm making a game. I plan on having 4 enemy types. I already made a class for one of them.

I'm new to C++ and I always was confused about Polymorphism and how and when to use it.

I need to know how I could create a class that acts as a base for all 4 of the enemy classes.

I know that with using OOP, one of the advantages is less code is used which means it's efficient. I'm not really asking for you to code a whole class for me, just asking how I could possibly use Polymorphism in this situation. Here is 1 of the 4 enemy classes. *(They all will look exactly the same without Polymorphism, the only thing that will change is the `chanceOfLoss` variable)*.

```
class Punk
{
    public:
        Punk(Player player)
        {
            chanceOfLoss = 50;
            this->player = player;
        }
        bool Fight()
        {
            chanceOfWin = chanceOfLoss + player.GetWeapon();
            randNum = 1 + rand() % 100;

            if (randNum <= chanceOfWin)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    private:
        Player player;
        int chanceOfLoss;
        int randNum;
        int chanceOfWin;
};
```

Comment: If the different enemy types only differ in the value of `chanceOfLoss`, then you shouldn't use a type hierarchy. Use a type hierarchy, if the enemy types behave differently.

Comment: I empathize on nosid comment: don't use inheritance in this case, just add a setter and a getter for `chanceOfLoss`.

Comment: I think you are confusing core OOP principles here. [Polymorphism][1] in C++ gives you the ability to program on abstractions, rather on implementations.

[Inheritence][2] gives you the ability to write common functionality for several classes.

Please refer to the following question: [link][3].


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming
  [2]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29
  [3]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973949/difference-between-inheritance-and-polymorphism

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is an example of how you can use Polymorphism in this situation.
You should  consider if it is the best choice, depending on all design considerations.

`class BaseEnemy` will be the base class of your enemies. Each enemy type will inherit from it, and override the `getChanceofLoss` method.
All enemies will share the same `Fight` method

```
class BaseEnemy
{
public:
   bool Fight()
   {
      chanceOfWin = getChanceOfLoss() + player.GetWeapon();
      ...
   }
   virtual int getChanceOfLoss() = 0;
}

class Punk: public BaseEnemy
{
public:
   virtual int getChanceOfLoss() { return 60; }    
}
```

Comment: This is excellent. I understand it too. The Base class's virtual method must be overriden by the derrived class's method and that returns its corresponding chanceOfLoss value. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: I didnt downvote, i tried pressing the up arrow but it said i needed 15 rep and as a result it decided to remove 1