# Difference between interface and polymorphism

Tags: c++, oop, interface, polymorphism

I was reading an online excerpt from a C++ book on polymorphism and interfaces. 
The book made a distinction between polymorphism and interfaces, and specified how to implement them in C++. However, I was always under the idea that interfaces in C++ (implemented using a base class with pure virtual functions) were nothing more than an application of polymorphism.
I would like to know the clear distinction between polymorphism and interfaces because the excerpt confused me.

Comment: [go through this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973949/difference-between-inheritance-and-polymorphism)

Comment: This tells what interfaces and polymorphism are. However, I am trying to draw a distinction. Interfaces just seem to be an application of polymorphism from what I understand

Comment: Not a good question, shows minimal effort. If this guy didn't bother to do a cursory google search, why the hell would he read my response.

Comment: It is like asking for the difference between a carburetor and transport. You can use a carburetor to aid some means of transport. But listing the differences is futile.

Comment: I did do a google search, and was unable to understand the differences. I came to SO to ask this because I was unable to find the answer to my question and thought I might find people who might resolve my question. Sorry, if I offended you in any way

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Polymorphism is the abstract concept of dealing with multiple types in a uniform manner, and interfaces are a way to implement that concept. Code that interacts with an interface can interact with any type that provides that interface.

Note that C++ has (at least) two forms of polymorphism: *dynamic* (i.e. run-time) polymorphism via interfaces formally defined by virtual functions, and *static* (i.e. compile-time) polymorphism via interfaces informally defined by the use of template parameters.

Comment: The latter form of polymorphism relates to generic programming. I was concerned with the former. So interfaces are one of way of implementing polymorphism. Thank you for your answer! It really helped me

Answer (score 0):

Typical C++ interfaces make use of virtual functions and polymorphism to provide the actual implementation. But polymorphism covers many other things, which is "not interfaces".

An interface is a base-class that can be used to a class that is passed back to something that accepts that interface. In some cases, a class may provide more than one interface:

```
 class MyClass: public InterfaceGUI, InterfaceAudio
 {
   .... 
 };
```

here, `MyClass` provides a class that interfaces both with the GUI and the Audio interfaces. This is a one case of multiple inheritance.

On the other hand:

```
 class Animal
 {
    int numLegs;
  public:
    Animal(int nLegs): numLegs(nLegs) {}
 };

 class Dog : public Animal
 {
    Dog() : Animal(4) { }
 };
```

here `Animal` is not a pure interface class, since it implements some functionality, and this is generally not a good design for an interface.

Comment: Your explanation confirmed that one of the applications of polymorphism is an interface, but polymorphism is an abstract concept, while interfaces are used in code design? Thanks for the answer. I was able to wrap my head around this concept.

Comment: Yes, like Juanchopanza says, Polymorphism is transport, Interface is a part of a car engine.

Answer (score 0):

What i understood from the concept of `polymorphism` and `Interface` is as follows:

1. **Polymorphism** :
    `Polymorphism` is nothing but having more than one form(As per all books).
    But As per the Object orientation when you relate it with the real life You will get to know that `Polymorphism` is nothing but having more than one form with same name or some other Quality but have one's own Patent quality which no one have.
   As per the programming: 
   A function with same name But different arguments **(Compile time Polymorphism)** and a Virtual function used for **Runtime Polymorphism** As explained [here](http://www.questionscompiled.com/answer/cpp/148/compile-time-polymorphism-and-run-time-polymorphism)

[Check this Example](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/)

2. **Interface**

An interface describes the behavior or capabilities of a C++ class without committing to a particular implementation of that class.

The C++ interfaces are implemented using abstract classes and these abstract classes should not be confused with data abstraction which is a concept of keeping implementation details separate from associated data.

For this purpose we use `Pure Virtual function`
For Reference you can go through this [Link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_interfaces.htm)

And for example you can use explanation by [Mats Petersson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21399750/3110262)

Hope this will help you to understand the basic senario.