# Should I declare/Initialize ArrayLists as Lists, ArrayLists, or ArrayLists of <Cat>

Tags: java, list, collections, arraylist

What is the difference in declaring a collection as such

```
public class CatHerder{
    private List cats;
    public CatHerder(){
        this.cats = new ArrayList<Cat>();
    }
}
//or
public class CatHerder{
    private ArrayList cats;
    public CatHerder(){
        this.cats = new ArrayList();
    }
}
//or
public class CatHerder{
    private ArrayList<Cat> cats;
    public CatHerder(){
        this.cats = new ArrayList<Cat>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should declare it as a `List<Cat>`, and initialize it as an `ArrayList<Cat>`.

[`List`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is an interface, and [`ArrayList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is an implementing class. It's almost always preferable to code against the interface and not the implementation. This way, if you need to change the implementation later, it won't break consumers who code against the interface.

Depending on how you actually use the list, you might even be able to use the less-specific [`java.util.Collection`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) (an interface which `List` extends).

As for `List<Cat>` (you can read that as "list of cat") vs `List`: that's Java's [generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html), which ensure compile-time type safely. In short, it lets the compiler make sure that the `List` only contains `Cat` objects.

---

```
public class CatHerder{
    private final List<Cat> cats;
    public CatHerder(){
        this.cats = new ArrayList<Cat>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've seen this argument being used many times before. But in what circumstance would you actually see it being necessary to declare the interface type? Is there a use case where one would initialize a specific collection type, add data to it and then a bit later change his mind about the collection type?

Comment: @EvilWashingMachine http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/225674/1845 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/505148/139010

Answer (score 4):

I would do the following.

```
public class CatHerder{
    private final List<Cat> cats = new ArrayList<Cat>();
}
```

Comment: 6 years later, assuming java 7+ I prefer to initialize with List<Cat> cats = new ArrayList<>();. I picked this up from the eclipse sonar plugin. Quoting Sonar rule id 2293, "Java 7 introduced the diamond operator (<>) to reduce the verbosity of generics code. For instance, instead of having to declare a List's type in both its declaration and its constructor, you can now simplify the constructor declaration with <>, and the compiler will infer the type."

Answer (score 2):

In order to ensure type safety, and because current Java compilers will complain if a generic type has no type argument, you should always specify a type explicitly - or `<?>` if you really don't care.

That said, unless you use something specific to the `ArrayList` class, you should use `List<Cat>` to avoid tying your code to a particular `List` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

As Matt already stated, using the most common Interface/Superclass is the best way to go here.
Make sure to always declare the Type that appears in your List, so make it a `List<Cat>` or even `List<? extends Cat>`

If, at some later point, you want to replace the `ArrayList` with, say, a `LinkedList`, you won't have to change the declaration, but only the instantiation.

Answer (score 1):

`List` is more flexible than `ArrayList`, `List<Cat>` is safer than `List`. so `List<Cat>` is good choice.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `List` is an interface and `ArrayList` is an implementation of the `List` interface (actually, it subclasses `AbstractList` and `implements List`). Therefore `List cats = new ArrayList()` is valid since `ArrayList` **is-a** `List`.

For this:

```
private List cats;
```

`cats` becomes a raw-type (there is no reference to the Generic Type for `List`), it hasn't been parameterised.

Your 3rd solution is correct (it solves your problem for option 1),

```
private ArrayList<Cat> cats;
```

you have bounded a Generic Type `E` for `List<E>` to a type `Cat`. Therefore, your instantiation of `cats` is valid as the generic bounding is the same.

Your 2nd solution allows that only `ArrayList` of `cats` can be instantiated. The other 2 options allows you to instantiate any object that **is-a** `List`, e.g. `LinkedList`.