# Assigning ArrayList to List

Tags: java

Is there any Difference between two lines in the following

```
 ArrayList<String> arrName =  new ArrayList<String>();
 List<String>      arrName =  new ArrayList<String>();
```

Thanks for Reply

Comment: I've seen the same question (even same text) between yesterday and today (but can't find it).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza. Even me.

Comment: Explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062982/java-oop-list-versus-arraylist-as-reference-type)

Comment: Oops I haven't Seen it  exists I am going to delete mine

Comment: @LloydSantos thanks, at least I know I'm not insane :)

Comment: Wow, 6 answer so far, and 3 people there can vote to close the question as duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost always the second one is preferred over the first one. The second has the advantage that the implementation of the `List` can change (to a `LinkedList` for example), without affecting the rest of the code. This is will be difficult to do with an `ArrayList`, not only because you will need to change `ArrayList` to `LinkedList` everywhere, but also because you may have used `ArrayList` specific methods.

Answer (score 3):

Try to hide specific implementation behind an Interface whenever possible. [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488212/should-i-declare-initialize-arraylists-as-lists-arraylists-or-arraylists-of-c)

Answer (score 2):

The latter is usually recommended as long as you only need a `List` interface later on. That's called "programming to interface, not implementation".

As for the detailed difference between them, I have answered in another question on stackoverflow: [The difference between "C c = new C()" and "A c = new C()" when C is a subclass of A in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14917903/the-difference-between-c-c-new-c-and-a-c-new-c-when-c-is-a-subclass/14918010#14918010)

Answer (score 2):

The second approach is usually the preferred one as it hides the implementation behind an interface.

This means that later on, if the requirements will change and will require another implementation of the `List` interface, you can change just one line of code and everything else will still work because you were coding to an interface not to a class.

Answer (score 2):

There is not much difference per se, but `List` shall be used whenever possible as it is an interface and you may see in standard libraries' methods parameters are generally `List<K>`, so that any specific implementation can be passed, like `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`.

Answer (score 2):

Second is example of  `Program to Interface` and its the preferred way.
For details [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)