# benifits of a interfaces

Tags: java, interface

suppose in case of class like

```
class  person
  {
     String name;
    public void setName()
     {
     }

      }
  class labor extends Person
      {
      }
```

in that case sub class can reuse the base class data member and function but in the case of interfaces

```
 interface person
  {

     public void setName();


  }
   class labor extends Person
      {
       }
```

here we have to give the implementation of a function then if we must have to give the implementation of a function than what is the benifit of a interfaces because if we have to give the definition then without interface we can write a new function in a class and do every thing?

Comment: Google is your best friend. For example, this article give an example of when you would want to use an interface: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html

Comment: The most obvious use is to define that 2 otherwise separate classes can both behave similarly in a single situation. For example the interface `Scannable` might be implemented by both buildings and people in a game because both can be scanned.  The Scanner class doesn't care what something is, only that it implements `Scannable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interfaces declare what behavior and characteristics an object **will** have when implemented. They are explicitly *abstract*, which is why you still need to define *actual* implementations on your objects later.

A fairly classic example and description was provided in the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504904/how-are-java-interfaces-actually-used).