# Why implement Comparable interface when you can define compareTo method in a class?

Tags: java, interface, comparable

You can define the `compareTo` method in a class without implementing the
`Comparable` interface. What are the benefits of implementing the `Comparable`
interface?

Comment: [What is the point of interfaces?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/131332/what-is-the-point-of-an-interface)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The benefit of implementing the interface is that some methods specifically *require* object that implements the `Comparable` interface. It gives them a guarantee that the object you're passing has a `compareTo` method with the correct signature.

There's no way in Java to have a method require that an object implement any given method (such as `compareTo`) in and of itself. To get around this, interfaces were created. Any time you have an object that you know is a `Comparable`, you also know you can call `compareTo` on it.

Comment: I'm still confused. Examples/analogies would help..

Comment: @Saud Did you look at the question of which yours was marked as a duplicate?

Comment: yeah but that didnt help either

Comment: @Saud I would advise just looking on the internet for more information about Java interfaces and learning that. If you *really* need help from Stack Overflow, put a bounty on [that other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504904/how-are-java-interfaces-actually-used) and explain what exactly you don't understand.