# Using an interface's method without writing any code after instantiating it

Tags: java, android, interface

i'm working my way through an android course online and i have some questions regarding the code, specifically about interfaces.

The Code:

```
package com.test.personalnotes;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * Created by Admin on 24/12/15.
 */
public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    public static interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position);

        public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position);
    }

    private OnItemClickListener mListener; <-- An interface variable..?
    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                //Gets the childview of the recyclerview (I.e What is beneath the area which was pressed)
                View childView = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());
                if (childView != null && mListener != null) {
                    mListener.onItemLongClick(childView, recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(childView)); <-- Code i'm unsure of No.1
                }
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        View childview = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(),motionEvent.getY());
        //If there is something under the area tapped,mListener is not ull and a touch event was registered
        if(childview != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)){
            mListener.onItemClick(childview,recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(childview)); <-- Code i'm unsure of No.2
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
}
```

From the code snipper above, where we are implementing a listener for a recyclerview, we create an interface OnItemClickListener with 2 methods and a variable mListener of type OnItemClickListener(The interface).

From what i understand of interfaces, from http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/what-is-an-interface-in-java.html & [Is there more to an interface than having the correct methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504904/how-are-java-interfaces-actually-used) , i know that the methods defined in an interface have to be implemented when the interface is implemented.

However, in the code snippet, we are actually able to create a variable of type OnItemClickListener(The interface)?

Qn1.

Do i assume the by creating an interface variable i am actually implementing it?

Qn2.

I do not actually have to implement the methods onItemClick & onItemLongClick in the interface? I say this because when i comment out one of the lines of code which i'm unsure of, i do not get any errors from android studio

Qn 3.

With the following line of code,

```
mListener.onItemClick(childview,recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(childview));
```

where we are instantiating the method, why are we able to do so without actually writing the code body for the method?

E.g

```
mListener.onItemClick(childview,recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(childview)){
    //Enter code here for handling the actual item click
    //For example, textView.setText(text);
};
```

Am i severely misunderstanding something about interfaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do i assume the by creating an interface variable i am actually implementing it?

No, the variable contains `null` until you assign to it an instance of a class that implements that interface, which you do in the line - `mListener = listener;`.

> I do not actually have to implement the methods onItemClick & onItemLongClick in the interface?

Nowhere in the code you posted are you implementing the `OnItemClickListener` interface. When you create a class that implements that interface, you'll have to implement all of its methods (unless that class would be abstract).

As for the last question :

```
public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
    ...
```

Your `RecyclerItemClickListener` constructor accepts the `listener` argument, which is a reference to an instance of a class that implements `OnItemClickListener`, and therefore implements all the methods of that interface. It then assigns it to `mListener`, so `mListener` can be used to execute any method of that interface.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, just to clarify, am i correct in saying that because the mListener variable is assigned the value of listener, which is an instance of a class(A) that implements OnItemClickListener, when i  call the line mListener.onItemLongClick, i am actually calling the onItemLongClick method as defined in class A, with all it's associated code.(E.g for handling the itemlongclick?)